# How do I get the correct id from flask-sqlalchemy when autoincrement id from def __init__() in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I get the correct id from flask-sqlalchemy when autoincrement id from  def **init**() in flask-sqlalchemy ?Also if I want to db.add(id) id how do I do that?

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
      
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    
    confirmation_email = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False) 
    reset_email_password = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    



def __init__ (self , id: int, username: str,  email: str, plaintext_password: str, confirmation_email=False, reset_email_password=False): 
    self.id = id
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    # Hashing the password ( bytes, salt)
    plaintext_password = 'pojkp[kjpj[pj'
    self.hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(plaintext_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    self.confirmation_email = confirmation_email 
    self.reset_email_password = reset_email_password
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `self.id = id` will work, but possibly at the cost of messing up the database's autoincrement behaviour.  I'd suggest either setting the ids manually or letting the database do it , but don't mix the two techniques.  Personally I would leave it to the database.  There are are few, if any, good use cases for manually setting autoincrementing ids.

Comment: I just thought of an idea query the database with something like username then get the all the usernames in a variable called ```user```. Then would using ```number_of_ids = len(user.id)```  Then do this ```new_user_id =number_of_ids+1``` . Will this work?

Also can I just go ```self.id = id``` in ```def_init__()```

Comment: Just wanted to add I would have to query the database with id = 1, instead. But what if I have 0 users at this point, I guess I put it in a try.

Comment: Such techniques will only work in simple applications.  They will break if two new records are being created at the same time.  In general your program should not care about the value of ids.  Queries on n empty table should be fine; they will either return an empty list or `None`, depending on whether you call `.first()` or `.all()` etc

Comment: This is just for pytesting and it is deleted after , does that extra tidbit make a difference?

Comment: Also when would 2 records be created at the same time?